# set x axis in HH:MM format without missing time periods

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have OpenVPN as the VPN server at work. I've added a lot of additional features to it. I have user data usage logged to a MySQL database, laid out like so.

```
id              
username        
IP              
DateSessionStart
TimeSessionStart
SessionId       
DateLastUpdate  
TimeLastUpdate  
UserUploaded    
UserDownloaded
```

"SessionId" is the epoch time the session started. A user might have more than one session in a day, so I don't want to use `geom_line` with the "aes" "color" property set to "username" because the lines are joined from the end of one session to the start of the next, like the one below. "LW..."'s first session was short-lived, but it's end is joined to the start of their next session. This user is a bad example of this. I did encounter another user who was logged in past midnight, so their session ended with a few GB, then they had another session the same calendar day, so there was a long negative slanted line to "0 MB" when the next session started.

[image: geom_line with color = username]

I have this graph pretty close to how I want it.

[image: geom_line with color = SessionIdFac]

There are two things I'd like to change.

First, I'd like the x axis to start at midnight and end at the following midnight. I don't want gaps when no one was connected. Some of the `scale_x_...` additions seemed applicable, but they didn't have a noticeable effect between different days, and sometimes the x-axis labels were different day to day, e.g. listing Month and day with HH:MM, and another only HH:MM was listed.

Second, I want each session to be identified by its own color, but I'd like the legend to show the username for the session, not the SessionId value. I'm not sure how, if it's possible, to change the values of the Legend. I generated labels for each distinct session using `ggrepel::geom_label_repel`, and I `paste`d the username, total data used (sum of download and upload), newline, and the last four digits of the "SessionId". Side note, I used `mutate` to create "SessionIdFac" as a factor of "SessionId" because using `color=SessionId`, where "SessionId" is an int, made a continuously shaded color value in the legend.

Ideally, I'd have the username in the legend for each session, like the sample rectangled in blue. I'd be okay with the portion rectangled in red, where the last four digits were substringed with `stringr`.

This is the full script.

```
require(RMySQL)
require(tidyverse)
require(stringr)

con = dbConnect(MySQL(),
    user     = "OpenVpnBandwidthUsage",
    password = "OpenVpnBandwidthUsage",
    dbname   = "OvpnDb",
    host     = "172.16.2.100")

on.exit(dbDisconnect(con))

(DateOfVpnTransactions = Sys.Date()-7)

SqlStatement = paste(sep='',
  "select " ,
    "username , " ,
    "IP , " ,
    "DateSessionStart , " ,
    "TimeSessionStart ," ,
    "SessionId ," , 
    "DateLastUpdate ," , 
    "TimeLastUpdate," , 
    "UserUploaded + UserDownloaded as 'TotalBandwidth' " ,
  "from Bandwidth " , 
  "where DateLastUpdate = '" , DateOfVpnTransactions , "' " ,
  "order by DateLastUpdate , TimeLastUpdate , username;"
) ; SqlStatement

results = dbSendQuery(con, SqlStatement)
data = fetch(results , n=-1)
huh = dbHasCompleted(results)
dbClearResult(results)
dbDisconnect(con)

EndpointLabels = data %>% 
  group_by(SessionId) %>% 
  mutate(label = if_else(TimeLastUpdate == max(TimeLastUpdate), paste(sep='', username, ': ', TotalBandwidth, ' MB', '\n[', str_sub(SessionId,-4), ']'), NA_character_)) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  select(label)

DATA = data %>% 
  mutate(
    label_flag         = EndpointLabels$label,
    username           = as.factor(username),
    IP                 = as.factor(IP),
    SessionIdFac       = as.factor(SessionId),
    DateLastUpdate     = as.Date(DateLastUpdate),
    DateTimeLastUpdate = as.POSIXct(paste(DateLastUpdate, TimeLastUpdate), tz='EST')
    )

(MaxData=max(DATA$TotalBandwidth))

cat('Start:' , '\t', format(as.POSIXct(paste(DateOfVpnTransactions, '00:00:00')), '%D %r'))
cat('End:'   , '\t', format(as.POSIXct(paste(DateOfVpnTransactions, '23:59:59')), '%D %r'))

DATA %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=DateTimeLastUpdate, y=TotalBandwidth)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color=SessionIdFac), show.legend = TRUE) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=SessionIdFac), show.legend = TRUE) + 
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(aes(label=label_flag), na.rm=TRUE) +
  labs(
    title    = 'OpenVPN Bandwidth usage',
    subtitle = 'Separated by discrete session',
    x        = 'Time of Day',
    y        = 'Bandwidth used',
    color    = 'Session'
  ) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90 , hjust = 1))

ggsave(paste(sep='', DateOfVpnTransactions, '.png'), device='png', path='c:\\temp\\', width=8, height=5)
```

**EDIT**: Including some requested info.

```
DATA %>% str ; DATA %>% head(20) ; DATA %>% tail(20)
'data.frame':   569 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ username          : Factor w/ 3 levels "cr...","rg...",..: 3 2 3 2 3 2 2 3 3 2 ...
 $ IP                : Factor w/ 3 levels "1.2.3.158",..: 1 3 1 3 1 3 3 1 1 3 ...
 $ DateSessionStart  : chr  "2019-03-21" "2019-03-21" "2019-03-21" "2019-03-21" ...
 $ TimeSessionStart  : chr  "21:01:00" "22:14:39" "21:01:00" "22:14:39" ...
 $ SessionId         : int  1553216460 1553220879 1553216460 1553220879 1553216460 1553220879 1553220879 1553216460 1553216460 1553220879 ...
 $ DateLastUpdate    : Date, format: "2019-03-22" "2019-03-22" "2019-03-22" "2019-03-22" ...
 $ TimeLastUpdate    : chr  "00:00:44" "00:00:53" "00:01:50" "00:01:53" ...
 $ TotalBandwidth    : num  140 2 140 2 140 2 2 140 140 2 ...
 $ label_flag        : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ SessionIdFac      : Factor w/ 7 levels "1553216460","1553220879",..: 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 ...
 $ DateTimeLastUpdate: POSIXct, format: "2019-03-22 00:00:44" "2019-03-22 00:00:53" "2019-03-22 00:01:50" "2019-03-22 00:01:53" ...

    username  IP         DateSessionStart  TimeSessionStart  SessionId   DateLastUpdate  TimeLastUpdate  TotalBandwidth  label_flag             SessionIdFac  DateTimeLastUpdate
1   rs...     1.2.3.158  2019-03-21        21:01:00          1553216460  2019-03-22      00:00:44        140             <NA>                   1553216460    2019-03-22 00:00:44
2   rg...     2.3.4.242  2019-03-21        22:14:39          1553220879  2019-03-22      00:00:53          2             <NA>                   1553220879    2019-03-22 00:00:53
3   rs...     1.2.3.158  2019-03-21        21:01:00          1553216460  2019-03-22      00:01:50        140             <NA>                   1553216460    2019-03-22 00:01:50
4   rg...     2.3.4.242  2019-03-21        22:14:39          1553220879  2019-03-22      00:01:53          2             <NA>                   1553220879    2019-03-22 00:01:53
5   rs...     1.2.3.158  2019-03-21        21:01:00          1553216460  2019-03-22      00:02:50        140             <NA>                   1553216460    2019-03-22 00:02:50
6   rg...     2.3.4.242  2019-03-21        22:14:39          1553220879  2019-03-22      00:02:54          2             <NA>                   1553220879    2019-03-22 00:02:54
7   rg...     2.3.4.242  2019-03-21        22:14:39          1553220879  2019-03-22      00:03:55          2             <NA>                   1553220879    2019-03-22 00:03:55
8   rs...     1.2.3.158  2019-03-21        21:01:00          1553216460  2019-03-22      00:03:55        140             <NA>                   1553216460    2019-03-22 00:03:55
9   rs...     1.2.3.158  2019-03-21        21:01:00          1553216460  2019-03-22      00:04:40        140             <NA>                   1553216460    2019-03-22 00:04:40
10  rg...     2.3.4.242  2019-03-21        22:14:39          1553220879  2019-03-22      00:04:55          2             <NA>                   1553220879    2019-03-22 00:04:55
11  rs...     1.2.3.158  2019-03-21        21:01:00          1553216460  2019-03-22      00:05:50        140             <NA>                   1553216460    2019-03-22 00:05:50
12  rg...     2.3.4.242  2019-03-21        22:14:39          1553220879  2019-03-22      00:05:56          2             <NA>                   1553220879    2019-03-22 00:05:56
13  rs...     1.2.3.158  2019-03-21        21:01:00          1553216460  2019-03-22      00:06:55        140             <NA>                   1553216460    2019-03-22 00:06:55
14  rg...     2.3.4.242  2019-03-21        22:14:39          1553220879  2019-03-22      00:06:57          2             <NA>                   1553220879    2019-03-22 00:06:57
15  rs...     1.2.3.158  2019-03-21        21:01:00          1553216460  2019-03-22      00:07:52        140             <NA>                   1553216460    2019-03-22 00:07:52
16  rg...     2.3.4.242  2019-03-21        22:14:39          1553220879  2019-03-22      00:07:58          2             <NA>                   1553220879    2019-03-22 00:07:58
17  rs...     1.2.3.158  2019-03-21        21:01:00          1553216460  2019-03-22      00:08:55        140             <NA>                   1553216460    2019-03-22 00:08:55
18  rg...     2.3.4.242  2019-03-21        22:14:39          1553220879  2019-03-22      00:08:58          2             <NA>                   1553220879    2019-03-22 00:08:58
19  rs...     1.2.3.158  2019-03-21        21:01:00          1553216460  2019-03-22      00:09:54        140             <NA>                   1553216460    2019-03-22 00:09:54
20  rg...     2.3.4.242  2019-03-21        22:14:39          1553220879  2019-03-22      00:09:58          2             <NA>                   1553220879    2019-03-22 00:09:58
550 cr...     4.5.6.150  2019-03-22        08:47:54          1553258874  2019-03-22      11:51:51        376             <NA>                   1553258874    2019-03-22 11:51:51
551 cr...     4.5.6.150  2019-03-22        08:47:54          1553258874  2019-03-22      11:52:52        376             <NA>                   1553258874    2019-03-22 11:52:52
552 cr...     4.5.6.150  2019-03-22        08:47:54          1553258874  2019-03-22      11:53:55        380             <NA>                   1553258874    2019-03-22 11:53:55
553 cr...     4.5.6.150  2019-03-22        08:47:54          1553258874  2019-03-22      11:54:55        383             <NA>                   1553258874    2019-03-22 11:54:55
554 cr...     4.5.6.150  2019-03-22        08:47:54          1553258874  2019-03-22      11:55:55        386             <NA>                   1553258874    2019-03-22 11:55:55
555 cr...     4.5.6.150  2019-03-22        08:47:54          1553258874  2019-03-22      11:56:55        388             <NA>                   1553258874    2019-03-22 11:56:55
556 cr...     4.5.6.150  2019-03-22        08:47:54          1553258874  2019-03-22      11:57:55        391             <NA>                   1553258874    2019-03-22 11:57:55
557 cr...     4.5.6.150  2019-03-22        08:47:54          1553258874  2019-03-22      11:58:55        395             <NA>                   1553258874    2019-03-22 11:58:55
558 cr...     4.5.6.150  2019-03-22        08:47:54          1553258874  2019-03-22      11:59:55        395             <NA>                   1553258874    2019-03-22 11:59:55
559 cr...     4.5.6.150  2019-03-22        08:47:54          1553258874  2019-03-22      12:00:55        395             <NA>                   1553258874    2019-03-22 12:00:55
560 cr...     4.5.6.150  2019-03-22        08:47:54          1553258874  2019-03-22      12:01:56        395             <NA>                   1553258874    2019-03-22 12:01:56
561 cr...     4.5.6.150  2019-03-22        08:47:54          1553258874  2019-03-22      12:02:55        396             <NA>                   1553258874    2019-03-22 12:02:55
562 cr...     4.5.6.150  2019-03-22        08:47:54          1553258874  2019-03-22      12:03:56        400             <NA>                   1553258874    2019-03-22 12:03:56
563 cr...     4.5.6.150  2019-03-22        08:47:54          1553258874  2019-03-22      12:04:56        412             <NA>                   1553258874    2019-03-22 12:04:56
564 cr...     4.5.6.150  2019-03-22        08:47:54          1553258874  2019-03-22      12:05:56        418             <NA>                   1553258874    2019-03-22 12:05:56
565 cr...     4.5.6.150  2019-03-22        08:47:54          1553258874  2019-03-22      12:06:56        419             <NA>                   1553258874    2019-03-22 12:06:56
566 cr...     4.5.6.150  2019-03-22        08:47:54          1553258874  2019-03-22      12:07:56        420             <NA>                   1553258874    2019-03-22 12:07:56
567 cr...     4.5.6.150  2019-03-22        08:47:54          1553258874  2019-03-22      12:08:56        423             <NA>                   1553258874    2019-03-22 12:08:56
568 cr...     4.5.6.150  2019-03-22        08:47:54          1553258874  2019-03-22      12:09:56        426             <NA>                   1553258874    2019-03-22 12:09:56
569 cr...     4.5.6.150  2019-03-22        08:47:54          1553258874  2019-03-22      12:10:56        427             cr...: 427 MB\n[8874]  1553258874    2019-03-22 12:10:56
```

dput(DATA), massaged to match data above.

```
structure(list(

username = structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("cr...", "rg...", "rs..."), class = "factor"), 

IP = structure(c(1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("108.236.141.158", "24.101.215.15", "71.72.44.242"), 
class = "factor"), 

DateSessionStart = c("2019-03-21", "2019-03-21", "2019-03-21", "2019-03-21", 
"2019-03-21", "2019-03-21", "2019-03-21", "2019-03-21", "2019-03-21", 
"2019-03-21", "2019-03-21", "2019-03-21", "2019-03-21", "2019-03-21", 
"2019-03-21", "2019-03-21", "2019-03-21", "2019-03-21", "2019-03-21", 
"2019-03-21", "2019-03-22", "2019-03-22", "2019-03-22", "2019-03-22", 
"2019-03-22", "2019-03-22", "2019-03-22", "2019-03-22", "2019-03-22", 
"2019-03-22", "2019-03-22", "2019-03-22", "2019-03-22", "2019-03-22", 
"2019-03-22", "2019-03-22", "2019-03-22", "2019-03-22", "2019-03-22", 
"2019-03-22"), 

TimeSessionStart = c("21:01:00", "22:14:39", "21:01:00", "22:14:39", "21:01:00", 
"22:14:39", "22:14:39", "21:01:00", "21:01:00", "22:14:39", "21:01:00", 
"22:14:39", "21:01:00", "22:14:39", "21:01:00", "22:14:39", "21:01:00", 
"22:14:39", "21:01:00", "22:14:39", "08:47:54", "08:47:54", "08:47:54", 
"08:47:54", "08:47:54", "08:47:54", "08:47:54", "08:47:54", "08:47:54", 
"08:47:54", "08:47:54", "08:47:54", "08:47:54", "08:47:54", "08:47:54", 
"08:47:54", "08:47:54", "08:47:54", "08:47:54", "08:47:54"), 

SessionId = c(1553216460L, 1553220879L, 1553216460L, 1553220879L, 1553216460L, 
1553220879L, 1553220879L, 1553216460L, 1553216460L, 1553220879L, 1553216460L, 
1553220879L, 1553216460L, 1553220879L, 1553216460L, 1553220879L, 1553216460L, 
1553220879L, 1553216460L, 1553220879L, 1553258874L, 1553258874L, 1553258874L, 
1553258874L, 1553258874L, 1553258874L, 1553258874L, 1553258874L, 1553258874L, 
1553258874L, 1553258874L, 1553258874L, 1553258874L, 1553258874L, 1553258874L, 
1553258874L, 1553258874L, 1553258874L, 1553258874L, 1553258874L), 

DateLastUpdate = structure(c(17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 
17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 
17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 
17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 
17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 
17977, 17977, 17977), class = "Date"), 

TimeLastUpdate = c("00:00:44", "00:00:53", "00:01:50", "00:01:53", "00:02:50", 
"00:02:54", "00:03:55", "00:03:55", "00:04:40", "00:04:55", "00:05:50", 
"00:05:56", "00:06:55", "00:06:57", "00:07:52", "00:07:58", "00:08:55", 
"00:08:58", "00:09:54", "00:09:58", "11:51:51", "11:52:52", "11:53:55", 
"11:54:55", "11:55:55", "11:56:55", "11:57:55", "11:58:55", "11:59:55", 
"12:00:55", "12:01:56", "12:02:55", "12:03:56", "12:04:56", "12:05:56", 
"12:06:56", "12:07:56", "12:08:56", "12:09:56", "12:10:56"), 

TotalBandwidth = c(140, 2, 140, 2, 140, 2, 2, 140, 140, 2, 140, 2, 140, 2, 140, 
2, 140, 2, 140, 2, 376, 376, 380, 383, 386, 388, 391, 395, 395, 395, 395, 396, 
400, 412, 418, 419, 420, 423, 426, 427), 

label_flag = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "cr...: 427 MB\n[8874]"), 

SessionIdFac = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("1553216460", "1553220879", "1553239153", "1553240262", "1553244013", 
"1553258796", "1553258874"), class = "factor"), 

DateTimeLastUpdate = structure(c(1553230844, 1553230853, 1553230910, 1553230913, 
1553230970, 1553230974, 1553231035, 1553231035, 1553231080, 1553231095, 
1553231150, 1553231156, 1553231215, 1553231217, 1553231272, 1553231278, 
1553231335, 1553231338, 1553231394, 1553231398, 1553273511, 1553273572, 
1553273635, 1553273695, 1553273755, 1553273815, 1553273875, 1553273935, 
1553273995, 1553274055, 1553274116, 1553274175, 1553274236, 1553274296, 
1553274356, 1553274416, 1553274476, 1553274536, 1553274596, 1553274656), 
class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "EST")), class = "data.frame", 

row.names = c(NA, -569L))
```

Comment: Instead of showing the full script, which includes many details that we can't verify because we don't have access to your data source, can you include the output from `dput(DATA)`?

Comment: @Z.Lin, that's a lot of data to paste. Would 20 rows or so of the `head` or `tail` output help?

Comment: Depends. Do 20 rows adequately reflect the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

For your first problem, I would try `expand_limits()` 
If you have a column only for the time then something like this should work:

```
ggplot(...) +
geom_point(...) +
expand_limits(x =c(hms::as.hms("00:00:00"),hms::as.hms("23:59:00")))
```

alternatively, you need to define a date-time for the limits.

Here are two alternatives with labeling the session with the user name

```
# create a named vector for the legend
user <- user_tmp %>% pull(username)
names(user) <- user_tmp$SessionId

# alternative one multiple days in a chart 
# own column for times needs to be converted into a time
DATA <- DATA %>% 
  mutate(TimeLastUpdate = hms::as.hms(TimeLastUpdate))

# alternative one plot with times column
DATA %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = TimeLastUpdate, y = TotalBandwidth, color = 
  SessionIdFac)) +
  geom_line() +
  expand_limits(x =c(hms::as.hms("00:00:00"),hms::as.hms("23:59:00"))) + #expand limits on the time
  scale_color_discrete(labels = user) # labels the sessions with the user name

  # alternative 2 plotting one day with datetime column
  DATA %>% 
   filter(DateLastUpdate == "2019-03-22") %>%  # filter on the day
   ggplot(aes(x = DateTimeLastUpdate, y = TotalBandwidth, color = SessionIdFac )) +
   geom_line() +
   expand_limits(x = c(as.POSIXct("2019-03-22 00:00:00"),  
   as.POSIXct("2019-03-22 23:59:00"))) + # expand limits for the day
   scale_color_discrete(label = user) # label the sessions with user name
```

Comment: When I add `expand_limits` as you have it written, I get an error, `Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only`. I've edited my question to include the `str` of DATA, and a few rows of the dataset. The x-axis labels, "DateTimeLastUpdate", is of type POSIXct.